# How to use append_file function with new line space in File::Slurp module

Tags: perl, cgi

Hi I'm using File::Slurp module to append values to the text file.

Code:

```
use strict;
use File::Slurp;
my @paramsArray;
my $appendName = "value1";
my $appendVaue = "value2";  
push (@paramsArray, "$appendName");
push (@paramsArray, "$appendVaue");
append_file( $filename, map { "$_\n" } @paramsArray ) ;
```

Output:

```
value1,value2
```

But I want the output like below.

```
value1
value2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you please check your output file again? Because I have tried the code you pasted and I can see the output file exactly same as you expected. I think your solution is already working.

Comment: Thanks Samiron. It is working fine :)